# Interpreter resolve get/put method only resolves the first access to a field

Tags: java, jvm, interpreter, jvm-hotspot, openjdk-21

I am trying to log every access to a field/static variable for an analysis tool I'm building, so far I have found this interpreter rt function,

```cpp
    void InterpreterRuntime::resolve_get_put(JavaThread* current, Bytecodes::Code bytecode) {
      // resolve field
      fieldDescriptor info;
      LastFrameAccessor last_frame(current);
      constantPoolHandle pool(current, last_frame.method()->constants());
      methodHandle m(current, last_frame.method());
      bool is_put    = (bytecode == Bytecodes::_putfield  || bytecode == Bytecodes::_nofast_putfield ||
                        bytecode == Bytecodes::_putstatic);
      bool is_static = (bytecode == Bytecodes::_getstatic || bytecode == Bytecodes::_putstatic);
    
      {
        JvmtiHideSingleStepping jhss(current);
        JavaThread* THREAD = current; // For exception macros.
        LinkResolver::resolve_field_access(info, pool, last_frame.get_index_u2_cpcache(bytecode),
                                           m, bytecode, CHECK);
      } // end JvmtiHideSingleStepping

       fprintf(stderr, "%s access to %s.%s%s\n",
          is_put ? "put" : "get",
          info.field_holder()->external_name(),
          info.name()->as_C_string(),
          info.signature()->as_C_string());
    
      // check if link resolution caused cpCache to be updated
      ConstantPoolCacheEntry* cp_cache_entry = last_frame.cache_entry();
      if (cp_cache_entry->is_resolved(bytecode)) return;
    
      // compute auxiliary field attributes
      TosState state  = as_TosState(info.field_type());
    
      // Resolution of put instructions on final fields is delayed. That is required so that
      // exceptions are thrown at the correct place (when the instruction is actually invoked).
      // If we do not resolve an instruction in the current pass, leaving the put_code
      // set to zero will cause the next put instruction to the same field to reresolve.
    
      // Resolution of put instructions to final instance fields with invalid updates (i.e.,
      // to final instance fields with updates originating from a method different than <init>)
      // is inhibited. A putfield instruction targeting an instance final field must throw
      // an IllegalAccessError if the instruction is not in an instance
      // initializer method <init>. If resolution were not inhibited, a putfield
      // in an initializer method could be resolved in the initializer. Subsequent
      // putfield instructions to the same field would then use cached information.
      // As a result, those instructions would not pass through the VM. That is,
      // checks in resolve_field_access() would not be executed for those instructions
      // and the required IllegalAccessError would not be thrown.
      //
      // Also, we need to delay resolving getstatic and putstatic instructions until the
      // class is initialized.  This is required so that access to the static
      // field will call the initialization function every time until the class
      // is completely initialized ala. in 2.17.5 in JVM Specification.
      InstanceKlass* klass = info.field_holder();
      bool uninitialized_static = is_static && !klass->is_initialized();
      bool has_initialized_final_update = info.field_holder()->major_version() >= 53 &&
                                          info.has_initialized_final_update();
      assert(!(has_initialized_final_update && !info.access_flags().is_final()), "Fields with initialized final updates must be final");
    
      Bytecodes::Code get_code = (Bytecodes::Code)0;
      Bytecodes::Code put_code = (Bytecodes::Code)0;
      if (!uninitialized_static) {
        get_code = ((is_static) ? Bytecodes::_getstatic : Bytecodes::_getfield);
        if ((is_put && !has_initialized_final_update) || !info.access_flags().is_final()) {
          put_code = ((is_static) ? Bytecodes::_putstatic : Bytecodes::_putfield);
        }
      }
    
      cp_cache_entry->set_field(
        get_code,
        put_code,
        info.field_holder(),
        info.index(),
        info.offset(),
        state,
        info.access_flags().is_final(),
        info.access_flags().is_volatile()
      );
    }
```

However, this only logs the first access to a field/static variable, I am assuming that this is then cached and placed on some table to be used later for faster access, but I didn't find anything useful so far.

Where is the caching taking place and is there a way to get every access, maybe I should edit cpu specific code?

P.S I am using **openjdk 21**  and the file can be found at `src/hotspot/share/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify JDK code to trace field access.
JVM Tool Interface (JVM TI) is desgined specifically for such tools. See [SetFieldAccessWatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#fieldWatch).

Alternatively, you may create a bytecode instrumentation agent that modifies loaded classes by adding a call to your tracing method next to each `getfield/putfield/getstatic/putstatic` bytecode.

Comment: Interesting. I was modifying the jdk code since I wanted to do that at runtime, probably by just adding a switch (e.g java -analyze... Classfile), what I am really trying to do is find data races. Would your proposal have a big performance impact?

Comment: @loukritios Bytecode instrumentation will be the most efficient. Interpreter-only solution (including JVM TI field watches) are all slow by definition, since they cannot benefit from JIT compilation.